# passing an object with value to new dialogue

Tags: c#, botframework

Is there a way to pass an object instance to the new dialogue for the proactive conversation. I want to send some custom data to the dialogue which will be used proactively to send the information to the user.

E.g.

```
ProactiveMessage messageDetails = new ProactiveMessage() {
    Message = “Hello User”,
    Details = “blah blah”
}
```

I want to send that object to the new dialogue so that I can use while constructing the message to the user.

```
using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
    var botData = scope.Resolve<IBotData>();
    await botData.LoadAsync(CancellationToken.None);

    //This is our dialog stack
    var stack = scope.Resolve<IDialogTask>();

    //interrupt the stack. This means that we're stopping whatever conversation that is currently happening with the user
    //Then adding this stack to run and once it's finished, we will be back to the original conversation
    var dialog = new ProactiveDialog();
    stack.Call(dialog.Void<object, IMessageActivity>(), null);
    await stack.PollAsync(CancellationToken.None);

    //flush dialog stack
    await botData.FlushAsync(CancellationToken.None);

}
```

Comment: You cannot start conversation before you know userId to which you'd like to send a proactive message, so user needs to send activity first (botAdded event). At the same time passing parameter to a ProactiveDialog is not  a big deal - just make it a part of contructor or use PrivateConversation data mechanism for example

Comment: @Artem it depends on the channel: it is not "necessary" to get a 1st message from user for email, Slack, Twilio SMS, ... where the IDs can be easily created

Comment: Im using DirectChannel where the userId and conversationId is same and I have it already persisted to resume the conversation. Question is, once we resume the conversation , how can we pass the data ? I couldnt successfully test the constructor method.